# How to use the value of input fields in an if statement

Tags: php, jquery

I have two input fields. One is to search auto suggest product names using [jquery.autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), and in my database I have column name `product left`, and I want to display it in the second input, is that possible?

For example: I have a product called `apple` with `product left` of `30`. `apple` will display in the first input field after typing, and at same time `30` must appear in the `second field`.

```
<form action="sales.php" method="post">
    <input name="productlist" type="text" id="productlist" size="20"/>
    <input name="productleft" type="text" value=""/>
</form>
```

**call jquery ui**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#productlist").autocomplete("psuggest.php", {
        selectFirst: true
    });
  });
  </script>
```

**inside psuggest.php**

```
<?php
    $q=$_GET['q'];
    $my_data=mysql_real_escape_string($q);
    $mysqli=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','saganatracker') or die("Database Error");
    $sql="SELECT pdesc FROM products WHERE pdesc LIKE '%$my_data%' ORDER BY pdesc";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());

    if($result)
    {
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo $row['pdesc']."\n";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Can you please add the code you're using to initialise the autocomplete on the first field, and also seeing the data returned from your database (I'm guessing JSON) would help a lot too.

Comment: Do you have a DataBase which store yours products ? Because if you want to perform such a process, you will need to use AJAX to load asynchronously some data.

Comment: edit my question above

Answer (score 0):

Use parameter `onselect` from `.autocomplete()` to bring the number of item left :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#productlist").autocomplete("psuggest.php", {
        selectFirst : true,
        onselect    : function(value, data) {
            $.post("myPhPfileWhichBringNumberOfItem.php", { product : value }, function(count) {
                $("#productleft").val(count); // Don't forget to mention an id for the input first
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Use JQuery post at the moment a value is selected, and then use a php script which open your database, go to the table and select number of product left (not sure if you should use `value` or `data`, please someone correct if I am wrong).

Comment: hi thank you for your answer but i am a little confuse how to make the the result of this will go to my second input field is there any to put in my input field to communicate to that query...

Comment: Yep, for sure, I am adding the code to put the `count` into your field.

Comment: I apply the changes but unfortunately not working the search product.

Comment: Do you made another php script to extract the number of product left ? Maybe ensure the query used is correct first.

Comment: yup : $query = "SELECT * FROM products";
  $npleft = mysqli_query($con, $query);
  $pleft = mysqli_fetch_assoc($npleft);
  echo $pleft['pleft'];